# Point in polytope that is farthest from the origin

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

Given the tall matrix ${\bf A} \in {\Bbb R}^{n \times m}$ (where $n > m$) and the vector ${\bf b} \in {\Bbb R}^n$,

$$ \max_{{\bf x} \in {\Bbb R}^m} \, \left\| {\bf x} \right\|_2 \quad \text{subject to} \, {\bf A} {\bf x} = {\bf b}, {\bf x} \ge {\bf 0}_m$$

I know from the construction that the constraints form a non-empty convex set, so a solution must exist. I am looking for an algorithm to find a solution to this optimization problem.

Comment: What is your norm $|x|$?

Comment: It's the Euclidean norm, so x^T x would also be possible.

Comment: and what does $x > 0$ means? each cordinate is positive?

Comment: Yes exactly, each coordinate must be positive.

Comment: Positive or non negative?

Comment: Oh, that's an error it must be non-negative.

Comment: You can apply the simplex algorithm?

Comment: How? My objective function is quadratic, not linear. Wouldn't I only get a feasible solution candidate for my problem?

Comment: It's non-convex.  Take a look at [these slides](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507030731/https://web.stanford.edu/class/cme334/docs/2011-11-17-Rubira_normmax.pdf)

Comment: Yes, I agree. I am taking a look at the slides you linked, thank you!

Comment: Given that your matrix is tall, it is already highly unlikely that the system $Ax=b$ has a solution, let alone $Ax=b$ *and* $x\geq 0$.  When they do, most often the solution will be unique, which makes this optimization problem moot.  This would have made much more sense for a wide matrix.  Otherwise the slides pointed in the comments discuss one possible solution.